# How to use locks in Rust?

Tags: concurrency, rust, locks

Do locks exist in Rust?  [The manual](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/rust.html) briefly mentions it but I can't find any implementation in the standard library.  If they exist, how do we use one?

Comment: I presume you are referring to [9.2.1 Communication between tasks](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/rust.html#communication-between-tasks)? What are you trying to do? As a general rule, you don't *need* locking because of Rust's task isolation and lack of data race.

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything in particular.  I was just wondering if the std lib provides a way to do it, and if so, how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Locks in Rust are mostly used to implement low level things in the runtime. As @chris-morgan said, you generally don't need locks. Normally the right way to synchronize between tasks is by passing messages.

If message passing doesn't meet your needs, ARCs might work: http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/extra/arc/index.html

Answer (score 2):

There are mutexes (and condition variables, etc.) in [`extra::sync`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/extra/sync/index.html), although one should use the higher-level wrappers for shared memory that Eric Holk mentions in [`extra::arc`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/extra/arc/index.html) if shared memory is all you need.